# Images on recycler view not loads

Tags: java, android, firebase, mobile, android-recyclerview

I have a application with users post when contains images, but the recycler view not loads any of these images from the firebase storage.I'm beginner on firebase and firebase storage, so maybe i'm doing something wrong. But if i copy the URL of a random image on google the image is loads correct.

**Image of my firebase real-time database:**

[image]

**PostModel.java:**

```
package com.sm.socialmeme;

public class PostModel {
    String name;
    String imgUrl;

    // constractors \\
    public PostModel(String name, String imgUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public PostModel(){

    }

    // getters and setters \\
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }
}
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.sm.socialmeme;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // global variables \\
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    List<PostModel> postList;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final ImageButton new_post = findViewById(R.id.new_post_btn);
        final ImageButton settings = findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        if (user == null) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

            mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        PostModel post = new PostModel();
                        post.setImgUrl(snapshot.child("imgUrl").getValue().toString());
                        post.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                        postList.add(post);

                        // notify adapter when a new item was addeted \\
                        if (recyclerAdapter != null){
                            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error: " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(HomeActivity.this,postList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            }
        });

        new_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UploadPhotoActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void clearList(){
        if (postList != null){
            postList.clear();
            if (recyclerAdapter != null){
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java:**

```
package com.sm.socialmeme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    List<PostModel> postList;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<PostModel> postList) {
        this.postList = postList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.post_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //PostModel postModel = postList.get(position);
        // set username \\
        holder.username.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
        // set image URL \\
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(postList.get(position).getImgUrl())
                .into(holder.postImg);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView username;
        ImageView postImg;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
            postImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the result is that nothing is displayed, right? Have you tried to set the adapter inside `onDataChange`, sight after `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Hello again, yes i have tried but is not working again, but if enter on the database a random url of a random image on google is loading the image correct.

Comment: I think this **[approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** might help.

Comment: @AlexMamo no is not fixed again.

Comment: "is not fixed" doesn't help us, help you. We need more info about what's wrong.

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, i need more info about the problem. :-)

Comment: @AlexMamo can you help me with this problem? :-)

Comment: As I already said, "is not fixed" doesn't help us, help you. We need more info about the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeSepetadelis post your model class code (PostModel)

Comment: @AlexMamo i add the code of the PostModel.java class in the question. The problem is when the recycler view do not load the images of the posts.

Comment: Have you tried to make the fields of the `PostModel` class private?

Comment: @AlexMamo what did you mean "fields" ?

Comment: Properties of class? Variables?

Comment: @AlexMamo i just try it.....and again is not working :-(